# Is it possible to use in-memory H2 database with MS SQL Server compatibility mode?

Tags: h2, in-memory-database

According to [documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility), H2 does not support compatibility mode with in-memory databases.

That is, in order to use H2 in MS SQL Server compatibility mode I need to write the JDBC URL `jdbc:h2:/Users/myuser/myfile.db;MODE=MSSQLServer`.

If I try something like `jdbc:h2:mem:my-db;MODE=MSSQLServer`, the compatibility mode is not turned on.

**Is there a way to use in-memory H2 in MS SQL Server compatibility mode?**

The end goal is to create a database in an automated test. I looked at [dockerized Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql-edge/disconnected-deployment) version and considered to use it in a TestContainers-based test. But I would prefer something simpler.

Comment: Where did you find that in documentation? Compatibility modes can be set for in-memory databases it exactly the same way as for persistent databases. Why do you think it isn't enabled and where exactly you specified this JDBC URL? You need to add more details to your question.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov I cannot post images, unfortunately. At http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#compatibility there is the text "To use the MS SQL Server mode, use the database URL jdbc:h2:~/test;MODE=MSSQLServer or the SQL statement SET MODE MSSQLServer.". I tried using it with in-memory H2 (version 2.1.214) and it did not work (e. g. `with (nolock)` was not ignored in this case).

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov If you know how to use the MS SQL server compatibility mode with in-memory databases, please post a sample URL here. Thanks.

Comment: `jdbc:h2:mem:my-db;MODE=MSSQLServer` is a correct URL.  Maybe you use Spring Boot? It ignores JDBC URL for unit tests, an additional configuration is needed.

Comment: @EvgenijRyazanov Yes, I was trying to use in Spring Boot tests. It would be great if you shared your "additional configuration".

Comment: You need to add `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.NONE)` annotation or you can add `spring: test: database: replace: none` to properties file.